# Iterate over a std::vector in sorted order

Tags: c++, sorting, loops, c++98

I receive from an API a vector of Foo as follows:

```
std::vector<Foo> foos;
```

I have then written a function called

```
std::vector<std::string> getKeys(const std::vector<Foo>&)
```

which iterates over the container and plucks out a key of type std::string for each Foo object.

How would you iterate over the Foo objects in foos in sorted order, where sorting is done on the key and in a case insensitive manner. Additionally, I'd prefer not to make a sorted copy of foos since it is large in size.

Here's my attempt, which works but I'm wondering if it can be done better.

```
struct CaseInsensitiveComparitor {
    bool operator ()(const std::pair<std::string, Foo&> lhs, const std::pair<std::string, Foo&> rhs) const {
        std::string str1 = lhs.first;
        boost::algorithm::to_lower(str1);
        std::string str2 = rhs.first;
        boost::algorithm::to_lower(str2);
        return (str1 < str2);
    }
};

// map key to Foo
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Foo*> > tempFoos;
{
   std::vector<std::string> keys = getKeys(foos);
   std::vector<std::string>::iterator begin = keys.begin();
   std::vector<std::string>::iterator i = keys.begin();
   std::vector<std::string>::iterator end = keys.end();
   for(;i!=end;++i)
   {
       tempFoos.push_back(*i, &foos[distance(begin,i)]);
   }

   std::sort(tempFoos.begin(), tempFoos.end(), CaseInsensitiveComparitor());
}

std::vector<Foo*> sortedFoos;
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Foo*> >::iterator i = tempFoos.begin();
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Foo*> >::iterator end = tempFoos.end();   
for(;i!=end;++i)
{
   sortedFoos.push_back(i->second);
}
```

Comment: What isn't working in your attempt?

Comment: @jamesj It works but I wondered if it could be done better or if it could be improved.

Comment: Please post the code you use and what you expect/want to happen. In the code you posted you access `sortedFoos` before you declare it, you increment `end` and not `i`, this is definitely not (part of) the code you attempted

Comment: How do the keys relate to the `Foo`s?

Comment: @Pieter I've now corrected the compilation errors in the code above but my question is from a design perspective. The code above gives an idea as to how I would solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You care currently iterating over foos three times and sorting it once. This is what will be making your algorithm less performant over large arrays. Why not change it to do the following

1. iterate over it to extract the pointers into a `std::vecotr<Foo*>` called fooPtrVec
2. Change your comparison function to dereference a Foo* and use the key field on Foo for the comparison. Call the function YourNewComparisonFunction
3. use `std::sort(fooPtrVec.begin(), fooPtrVec.end(), YourNewComparisonFunction())` to sort the vector of Foo*

Comment: Sounds like a better approach!

Comment: Less memory, less CPU cycles, less code than the other implementations... What's not to like? ;)

Comment: It depends on how keys are computed...

Comment: @Jarod42 you're right. I made an assumption that the key was just a field on the Foo objects. If it is calculated your answer makes more sense (+1 to you!)

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively to your attempt,
you may create an array of indexes

```
std::vector<size_t> indexes;
for (size_t i = 0; i != keys.size(); ++i) { indexes.push_back(i); }
```

using a comparator:

```
struct Comparator {
    explicit Comparator(const std::vector<string>& keys) : keys(&keys) {}

    bool operator ()(size_t lhs, size_t rhs) const {
        std::string str1 = (*keys)[lhs];
        boost::algorithm::to_lower(str1);
        std::string str2 = (*keys)[rhs];
        boost::algorithm::to_lower(str2);
        return (str1 < str2);
    }
private:
    const std::vector<string>* keys;
};
```

sort this indexes array

```
std::sort(indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), Comparator(keys));
```

Now you can iterates foos and/or keys with the indexes indirection:

```
std::vector<Foo*> sortedFoos;
for (size_t i = 0; i != indexes.size(); ++i) {
    sortedFoos.push_back(&foos[indexes[i]]);
}
```

Comment: +1 for the inversion of comparison logic

Comment: You still have to iterate over the collection an extra time to get the pointers. Why not sort the pointers in the first place?

Comment: Instead of making a local copy of the strings for each comparison (to make them lower case), how about writing a `char` comparator that calls `std::tolower` before comparing and then call `std::lexicographical_compare` on the two strings (which can now be stored locally as `const&` saving the copying and dynamic memory allocation).

Comment: @GuyGreer: if it was me, I would transform `keys` once with `tolower`, but I don't know if the OP's comparator was just an example and if keys may be modified.

Comment: @jamesj: The computation of `keys` may be expensive, so cannot be computed each time in the comparator (see the existing remarks to optimize this part to avoid the string copies in the previous comments).

Comment: @Jarod42 Fair enough, for some reason I thought he had a `std::map<std::string, Foo>` and wanted to output in case-insensitive order.  Simply calling `std::for_each(keys.begin(), keys.end(), boost::to_lower)` would definitely be easier.

Comment: Not less code, but as an alternative for that first `for` loop, C++11 provides `iota` to populate the indexes: `std::vector<size_t> indexes(keys.size());
    std::iota(indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), 0);`

Answer (score 1):

`for(;i!=end;++end)`

you have to increment your i not your end!

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake when copying my code. I've corrected this in my question.

Comment: @Baz How do you make such error when copying?

Comment: @BЈовић Well I had to replace my code with Foo so I haven't copied exactly :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a set to sort keys for you, and encapsulate them in a custom container for a more convenient usability:

```
class Foo
{
  public :
    Foo(const std::string & key) : key(key) {}
    const std::string & get_key() const { return key; }
  private :
    std::string key;
};

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & stream, const Foo & foo) { stream << foo.get_key(); return stream; }

class SortedFoo
{
  typedef std::set<std::pair<std::string,Foo*> > SortedFoos;
  SortedFoos mFoos;

public :
  SortedFoo(std::vector<Foo> & foos)
  {
    const std::vector<Foo>::iterator end = foos.end();
    for(std::vector<Foo>::iterator iter = foos.begin(); iter != end; ++iter)
    {
      mFoos.insert(std::make_pair(boost::algorithm::to_lower_copy(iter->get_key()), &(*iter)));
    }
  }

  class Iterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, Foo>
  {
    private:
      Iterator(SortedFoos::iterator iter) : mIter(iter) {}
      SortedFoos::iterator mIter;

    public :
      Iterator & operator ++ () { ++mIter; return *this; }
      bool operator != (const Iterator & other) const { return mIter != other.mIter; }
      Foo & operator * () { return *mIter->second; }
      Foo * operator -> () { return mIter->second; }

      friend class SortedFoo;
  };

  typedef Iterator iterator;

  iterator begin() { return Iterator(mFoos.begin()); }
  iterator end() { return Iterator(mFoos.end()); }
};

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
  std::vector<Foo> foos;
  foos.push_back(Foo("def"));
  foos.push_back(Foo("Jkl"));
  foos.push_back(Foo("yz "));
  foos.push_back(Foo("pqr"));
  foos.push_back(Foo("Mno"));
  foos.push_back(Foo("ghi"));
  foos.push_back(Foo("vwx"));
  foos.push_back(Foo("Abc"));
  foos.push_back(Foo("stu"));

  SortedFoo sorted(foos);
  std::copy(sorted.begin(), sorted.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Foo>(std::cout, " "));

  return 0;
}
```

If you have duplicate keys, you can't use a set. You can replace it by a vector with only a few modifications:

```
typedef std::vector<std::pair<std::string,Foo*> > SortedFoos;
//...
SortedFoo(std::vector<Foo> & foos)
{
  const std::vector<Foo>::iterator end = foos.end();
  for(std::vector<Foo>::iterator iter = foos.begin(); iter != end; ++iter)
  {
    mFoos.push_back(std::make_pair(boost::algorithm::to_lower_copy(iter->get_key()), &(*iter)));
  }
  std::sort(mFoos.begin(), mFoos.end());
}
//...
```