# the inherited class is not compatible with its parent when passing through an pointer agrument in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

Consider the following code: collection technically is a vector with sort method in addition.

```
template<class T>
class collection
{
public:
  std::vector<T> vec;
  void sort(sortType<T>* U, bool compare(T, T))
  {
      U->doSort(vec, compare) ;
  } 
}
```

And this is class sortType

```
template<class T>
class sortType
{
 protected:
   virtual void doSort(std::vector<T>&,  bool compare(T, T)){};
}
```

The following code is some different sorting methods that I want to use

```
template<class T>
class insertionsort : public sortType
{
 public: 
   void doSort(std::vector<T>&, bool compare(T, T))
    {
      //code of insertion sort
    } 
} 
template<class T>
class quicksort : public sortType
{
 public: 
   void doSort(std::vector<T>&, bool compare(T, T))
    {
      //code of quicksort
    } 
}
```

compare is a function look like this:

```
template <class T>
bool greater( T l, T r) 
{
    if (l<r) return true;
    return false;
}
```

I want to use the previous class like this:

```
insertionsort<int> U = insertionsort<int>();
collection<int> *Obj = new collection<int>();
Obj->sort(U, greater) ;    //error here!
```

Unfortunately, visual studio announced that I cannot pass the insertionsort class to sortType class. How could I fix it and use something like those previous. Thank for helpings

I have written a small code to test with same proplem

```
template<class T>
T doSomeThing(int a, int b, pheptoan<T>* U)
{
    return U->dopheptoan<int>(a, b);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int a = 6; int b = 7;
    phepcong<int>* U = new phepcong<int>();
    doSomeThing<int>(a, b, U);     //error here
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I believe it should be Obj->sort(&U, greater). I'm also not sure the way you define your compare argument is a valid syntax. Should be bool (*compare)(T, T) afaik

Comment: Why taking sort by interface and compare by pointer function ? compare might also have states.

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm not quire sure your meaning. I agree that I'm not professional when taking sort by interface but compare by pointer function. I thought I just need compare as greater or lesser so I did it

Comment: @user2717954 at first, I have also worry as you are but actually it worked

Comment: @TrầnNgọcDũng: By example you may want to sort `indexes` according to values stored in other array ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18636754/2684539) ).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you declare `sortType` before `collection`.

Your derived class should be declared as

`template<class T> class insertionsort : public sortType<T>`

`template<class T> class quicksort : public sortType<T>`

And `collection::sort` takes a pointer to `sortType`, so the last line should be `Obj->sort(&U, greater);'

Comment: I have write a small code for test this issue. The problem is not about inheritance. it;s trouble around the template. when I get rid of template and just use it with normal type like int, there's not thing happen. but when I change the code and use with template, the compiler anouced error

Comment: Because sortType is now a template class, when you inherit from it, you need to say sortType<T>, not just sortType.

Comment: You are inheriting from a template base class. So the template part is also part of the class type. That's why you need to include the template parameter in its name.